# SQL filter for rows in same table with nonmatching column combination

Tags: sql, join, filter, hsqldb

I am stuck with the following problem. Let's assume this table:
The database is `HSQLDB`

```
TABLE1
A    B

1    10
2    11
1    10
1    12 <---- not matching previous rows (B=10 is expected for A=1)
3    9
2    11
```

I want to make sure, that all rows are filtered which have "out of order" pairs of A,B. So in this case the result would be:

```
1    10
1    10
1    12
```

I came up with the following approach:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM TABLE1) INNER JOIN
(SELECT A as A2, B as B2 FROM TABLE1) ON A=A2
WHERE B!=B2
```

But this is kind of ugly, because a lot of joins are made if the table has a lot of matching entries for Column A. How would you approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to identify any column `A` where there is more than one `B` you can do this with a `COUNT`:

```
SELECT A, Count(B) as ct
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY A
HAVING ct > 1
```

Unfortunately though in order to pull back in column `B`, you would need to reference this set again:

```
SELECT A, B 
  FROM TABLE 1
  JOIN (
      SELECT A, Count(B) as Ct
      FROM TABLE1
      GROUP BY A
      Having ct > 1) identify on TABLE1.A = identify.A;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 t1 WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT * FROM TABLE1 t2 WHERE t1.A=t2.A AND t1.B<>t2.B
)
```